# Is there a way to extend a function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I will best explain the scenario with code.

```
  object Helper{
    fun getValuesForBlah1(constParam1 : Boolean, constParam2 : String, constParam3 : Float, varParam : Int)

    fun getValuesForBlah2(constParam1 : Boolean, constParam2 : String, constParam3 : Float, varParam : SomeClass)

    fun getValuesForBlah3(constParam1 : Boolean, constParam2 : String, constParam3 : Float, varParam : SomeOtherClass)
...
....
    }
```

If you look at all the functions, then have all have a set of common parameters and rest variable parameters. Is there a way to tell abstract out the common parameters so that I don't have to repeat them in all the functions?
**EDIT**
@Google has given a nice answer below.  But I am looking for a way in which it can be solved using some language feature. For eg in scala it can be solved using implicit (I am not sure though)?

Answer (score 2):

Just create class that holds common parameters:

```
object Helper {

    data class Param(
        val constParam1: Boolean,
        val constParam2: String,
        val constParam3: Float
    )

    fun getValuesForBlah1(param: Param, varParam : Int)

    fun getValuesForBlah2(param: Param, varParam : SomeClass)

    fun getValuesForBlah3(param: Param, varParam : SomeOtherClass)

}
```

Comment: Nice answer:) But looking for a way in which it can be solved using some language feature. Lilke for eg in scala it can be solved using implicit (I am not sure though)?

Comment: There is no language feature that solves your problem

Comment: @Ashwin It could be solved with union types which is a regularly requested feature, but language designers are reluctant to add them to Kotlin (they would bring a lot of complexity into the mix). See this [discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/union-types/77/4).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kotlin's [Any Class](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/). Any is the root of the Kotlin class hierarchy. Every Kotlin class has Any as a superclass.In your case you can implement your methods like:

```
object Helper {

    fun getValuesForBlah(constantParam1: Boolean, constantParam2: String, constantParam3: Float, varParam: Any) {
        if (varParam is Int) {

        } else if (varParam is SomeClass) {

        } else if (varParam is SomeOtherClass) {

        }
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
In OOP Approach you can do something like:

```
object Helper {

    data class Param(
        val constParam1: Boolean,
        val constParam2: String,
        val constParam3: Float,
        var varParam: Any
    )

    fun getValuesForBlah(param: Param){
            if (param.varParam is Int) {

            } else if (param.varParam is SomeClass) {

            } else if (param.varParam is SomeOtherClass) {

            }
            ....
            ....
      }

}
```

Hope it would be helpful for you. :)